# Testing a library that changes DOM directly

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, ui-testing, jsdom

I wrote a tiny library that manipulates DOM directly, using `window` and `document` to search and change the DOM. And now I'm trying to figure out how to test it.

So far I have tried a combination of [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) + [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom):

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>');

// these two lines do not seem to do anything useful:
global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;

test('can globally access and search the DOM', () => {
    // this doesn't work
    expect(global.document.querySelectorAll('p').length).toBe(1);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or am I entirely wrong with the testing approach? And if so, what would be the right way to approach such testing?

I feel a bit lost here, between what's called e2e testing and Unit testing, because in my case this seems to be something right in between.

Ideally, I would want to end up with this thing tested against multiple browsers, and to get some sort of test coverage. But that's more like the next step. Right now I cannot get it to work at all.

I know how fast things are moving in the Web world, so if I'm wrong completely, I appreciate if you can point me at what's the right way to do it today.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's my complete code, after a few suggestions from @duxfox, since with this approach my library is now missing event `DOMContentLoaded` which is supposed to trigger its DOM processing.

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

const { document } = (new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>')).window;
global.document = document;

global.window = document.defaultView;
window.console = global.console;

Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
    if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
        global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
    }
});

global.navigator = {
    userAgent: 'node.js'
};

// Here I'm trying to follow a suggestion from Luis:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803733/jsdom-dispatchevent-addeventlistener-doesnt-seem-to-work
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (ev) {
    console.log('DOMContentLoaded called!'); // this is not called.
    /*
    console.log('window click', ev.target.constructor.name,
        ev.currentTarget.constructor.name);*/
});

// loading my library here:
// const root = require('../src');

test('something', () => {

    // This now works, but my library is missing
    // event DOMContentLoaded to start processing the DOM

    expect(document.querySelectorAll('p').length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: would something like firing the domContentLoaded event manually work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153314/manually-dispatchevent-domcontentloaded wait sorry are you doing that already

Comment: or this: https://gist.github.com/chad3814/5059671

Comment: @duxfox-- I don't get it, using that piece of code I get error `TypeError: jsdom.env is not a function`. I'm using `jsdom` version `11.11.0`.

Comment: @duxfox--  LOL, just saw the last comment there: `Would you please redo the example using the new API? jsdom.env is deprecated as of jsdom v10.`. So, this doesn't work. What is the correct approach with the latest jsdom then? :)

Comment: lol idk, I saw that too, was just looking it up

Comment: what about this thing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom sorry that's an old unmaintained project...

Comment: or this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068932/jsdom-env-not-working-on-node-js-c9 lol sorry for all the links

Comment: did you try this code: `event = new window.Event("DOMContentLoaded", {bubbles: true});
document.dispatchEvent(event);` after the eventListener?

Comment: @duxfox-- Yes, that didn't work, as it works only inside browser, and not under Node.js, which overrides the `Event` object.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a jsdom setup script that I use with `mocha/chai/jsdom/enzyme`

looks like the `global.window` should be set to

```
dom.window.document.defaultView
```

rather than

```
dom.window
```

Full script, which adds other global properties:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

global.window = document.defaultView;
window.console = global.console;

Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

Comment: This seems to work on the surface. Right now it fails for me because inside the library it parses DOM only after initialization: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { /* process the DOM */});`. Any suggestion how solve this?

Comment: not sure what you mean - what's the significance of the `addEventListener` code you pasted? is that a test case or something?

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803733/jsdom-dispatchevent-addeventlistener-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {` is to start processing the DOM after the document has finished loading. But in our case that happens before the library is included. And If I include the library first instead, then it won't work because the global variables are not set up yet. So it's like a race thing.

Comment: ah I see what you're saying - can you post more of your code in the question so I can see it in context with the event listener etc.. maybe we can think of something

Comment: I am beginng to get the feeling of what should be the right approach, but I am yet to try and manage it work. I think, the best way is probably to use `JSDOM.fromFile` to load an HTML file that has all the library use cases inside it, but most importantly - include my library from inside it. Then, in theory, everything should just work. That's what I am trying to do right now...