# Mocking up CTRL + V event using Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm building an app that reads a CSV from the clipboard and turns it into an HTML table.

Here is the test:

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('Paste CSV and displays table correctly', async () => {
    
    let csv = [
        
        ['key', 'road', 'coord.lat',  'coord.lng', 'elem'],
        ['1',   'C-58', 42.02,        2.82,        ''],
        ['2',   'C-32', 41.35,        2.09,        ''],
        ['3',   'B-20', 41.44,        2.18,        '']
      
    ].map(e => e.join(`\t`)).join(`\n`);
    
    Object.assign(navigator, {
        clipboard: {
            readText: () => csv
        }
    });
    
    await render(<App />);
    
    document.dispatchEvent(
        new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            key: "v",
            ctrlKey: true,
            metaKey: true   
        })
    );
    
    await waitFor(() => expect(getByText('C-58')).toBeInTheDocument()); 
    
});
```

First, I'm mocking up the CSV and the `navigator.clipboard.readText()` function. Then, I'm trying to fire a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> event.

The problem is that the paste event isn't being fired. How can I simulate it in Jest?

Comment: Where does `waitFor` function come from? `react-testing-library`?

Comment: Yes, right. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804251/9504458) answers the question. I needed to add `bubbles: true` to the keyboard event because I was dispatching the event to `document`, so `window` wasn't seeing it.